# Chargebee api implementation with plan and subscription

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, payment-gateway

I am creating a software where my service user can create invoice and send that invoice to their customer from who they seek payment.
I also have option to pay invoice at once or in part payment for part payment the service user send the receipt to their customer.
So I am using chargebee to as a payment gateway so the customer's of my service user can pay the whole invoice or part of invoice as receipt. And I found out the payment can only be done by plan price and subscription.

So my question is how do I achieve that one way I thing is to create a plan for each payment(Receipt , Invoice ) issues from my system then use that plan id to make the payment. Then is it good way or it is the only way

Second is what is use of subscription since the checkout uses the plan id to do the payment Or is there any other way.

Please help me out guys I am really confused. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Chargebee is known for Subscription manage systmem . But That is not exactly true . If there will be payment method in created customer then through api you will be able to create invoice for the customer and will be able to charge them.

https://apidocs.chargebee.com/docs/api/invoices#create_invoice_for_charge

Subscripions  are used to charge customer for regular basis for their service . And plan is which you will have to create according to your requirement .